# while writing result into csv , format of number/text not getting set properly

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am writing data into csv. While doing so I have written below result into csv (size of file is in bytes).

`FNumber  Name      Size
1        Save.png  6.89766E+11`

I have tried to use string, long, double for size variable but it is not keeping text or number format for that. So written size is looks like above or sometime it is appending 000000 at end of size..

I want whole value should look like a number.

Please let me know how to set text/number setting before writing into csv

Thanks in advance

Comment: please show some code

Comment: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work

```
    static void WriteCsvFile()
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"<Path of the file>");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\output.csv", false);
        writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", "FNumber", "Name", "Size");
        writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2:D}", "1", "Save.bng", file.Length);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I am using above same code instead {2:D} ....but tried to adding {2:D}.......but getting exception.........Format specifier was invalid

Comment: Most probably the type of the variable that you store the size of the file is not long. Make sure the data type is long.